# ksh: zero divisor error when declaring a variable

Tags: ksh

**Update**: This is really weird. I looked further, and realized there are two `*ksh` packages in the server:

```
pdksh-5.2.14-37.el5_8.1.x86_64
mksh-39-7.el6_4.1.x86_64
```

and `mksh` is set in `/etc/alternatives`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Apr 23 10:39 /etc/alternatives/ksh -> /bin/mksh
```

I pointed it to `/bin/pdksh`, tried the script again, and it worked.

To replicate the issue, I changed it back to `/bin/mksh`, but this time, the script worked without error. In short, I could not replicate the issue anymore. Weird.

I'm looking further. Thanks.

---

Given this Korn shell script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

U=$1
```

with `$1` passed as `ABC/S0METHING`, how can I work around this error?

```
ksh: ABC/S0METHING zero divisor.
```

ksh version:

```
@(#)MIRBSD KSH R39 2009/08/01
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why that version of ksh seems to be forcing arithmetic evaluation on that variable assignment. What happens if you try: `U="$1"` with quotes?

Comment: Same thing. But if I do it this way: `U=\ABC/S0METHING`, it goes through without any error. However, `U` gets its parameter passed from another script, so I'm not sure how to pass it without some escape sequence.

Comment: are you saying that it is the 0 in the string "ABC/SOMETHING" that is causing the problem? If you change it from "0" to "O" it works? Also, Is this the complete context of the problem? (I don't get any error message). Please give us a self-contained test example. good luck.

Comment: Worksforme™ with `@(#)MIRBSD KSH R40 2012/02/11`.

Comment: What happens if you do `S0METHING=1; U=$1; echo $U`?

Comment: See my update. It works now, and I couldn't replicate the issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird, but if you are asking for workaround, it can be

```
U=`printf '%q' $1`
```

However, I am not able to replicate the problem on my system as I understand it...
So if this doesn't work, I shall remove the answer.